# pass data to welcome message

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

my register has a welcome message (email), it generates a random number

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        't_matricula' => $data['t_matricula'],
        'number' => rand(100, 9200),
        'matricula' => $data['matricula'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    Mail::to($user->email)->send(new WelcomeMail($user));
    
    return $user;
}
```

**the problem is that no welcome message arrives**

Comment: your `WelcomeMail` receives the `$user` as an arg so you can get the number from that

Comment: assuming you remove the `return` from the first line and also save that returned user to a var

Comment: Remove the return but now when registering the welcome email does not arrive, I think it does not find the $user variable

Comment: check error logs, welcomeMail class and mail configuration for debugging.

Comment: check the logs but nothing appears about WelcomeEmail. 
I tried manually sending a message with WelcomeEmail and if I send, the error is only in the registry